# django forms comments not visible

Tags: django, django-forms

i can add comments in db  and see its in admin panel but dont see added comments in posts (view_post.html).
i dont understand reason for this

models:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
name = models.CharField('Имя:', max_length=100)
create_date  = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
text = models.TextField()

def __str__(self):
    return '%s' % self.name
```

forms:

```
class CommentForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Comment
    fields = ['name', 'create_date', 'text']
```

views:

```
def view_post(request, slug):
post_detail = get_object_or_404(Article, slug=slug)
form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    comment = form.save(commit=False)
    comment.post_detail = post_detail
    comment.save()
    return redirect(request.path)
return render_to_response('view_post.html', {
    'post_detail': post_detail, 'form': form },
 context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

post template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block head_title %}{{ post_detail.title }}{% endblock %}
{% block title %}{{ post_detail.title }}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
{{ post_detail.body }}

{% if post_detail.comment_set.all %}
    {% for comment in post_detail.comment_set.all %}
       {{ comment.name }}
       {{ comment.text }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You set `comment.post_detail` to the current Article when saving, but there you don't actually seem to have a `post_detail` ForeignKey. In fact you don't seem to have any relationship between Comment and Article at all, or between Comment and anything.

Comment: thanks to your reply, I understood the reason for the problem